# How to use proxy from my computer in oder to ping a website?

Tags: proxy, ping

I have a non-static ip in my computer. But i want to use C# to write a program which ping a website through a proxy.

I collected 11 000 proxy in the world and i made a loop from 1 to 11 000. But:

When I ping a website, it uses my ip in computer instead of a proxy with its port.

I tried to make a tracert from a proxy to the website. It's ok. The problem is: Tracert is difference from ping.

Total, I mean that I want to make a loop from 1 to 11 000 with proxies and its port. then with a proxy, it will ping to the website.

It's like DoS.

Comment: ICMP (e.g. ping) doesn't really *have* a proxy functionality - you can't send ICMP pings through a HTTP proxy, if that's what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

hmm well you will need to connect to the proxy servers but the question is why do you want to connect to 11000 servers and ping?

My guess is nothing thats legal

Comment: Hi. I want to send a file to the website but it's allowed by firewall. So i may ping serveral times to social firewall, i will send the file to the website in the same time.